# JRuby + minitest failing because of ObjectSpace

Tags: rake, jruby

I am new to JRuby, and I'm trying to get my test suite running correctly. I'm using minitest, and it looks like minitest requires the ObjectSpace to be enabled. I've tried each of the following commands:

```
bundle exec jruby -X+O -S rake
jruby -X+O -S bundle exec rake
JRUBY_OPTS="-X+O" bundle exec rake
export JRUBY_OPTS="-X+O" && bundle exec rake
```

and all of them result in the following stack trace:

```
RuntimeError: ObjectSpace is disabled; each_object will only work with Class, pass -X+O to enable
each_object at org/jruby/RubyObjectSpace.java:167
     each at org/jruby/RubyEnumerator.java:189
     to_a at org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:375
      AWS at /Users/kshipley/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@split/bundler/gems/papi-38fc7d34a33d/lib/papi/aws.rb:1476
     Papi at /Users/kshipley/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@split/bundler/gems/papi-38fc7d34a33d/lib/papi/aws.rb:6
   (root) at /Users/kshipley/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@split/bundler/gems/papi-38fc7d34a33d/lib/papi/aws.rb:5
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at /Users/kshipley/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@split/bundler/gems/papi-38fc7d34a33d/lib/papi/aws.rb:157
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
  require at /Users/kshipley/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@split/bundler/gems/papi-38fc7d34a33d/lib/papi.rb:68
     each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1602
  require at /Users/kshipley/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
     each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1602
  require at /Users/kshipley/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55
  require at /Users/kshipley/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@global/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120
   (root) at /Users/kshipley/work/src/split/config/environment.rb:5
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at /Users/kshipley/work/src/split/config/environment.rb:3
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at /Users/kshipley/work/src/split/test/test_helper.rb:1
     load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063
 __file__ at /Users/kshipley/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@split/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5
     each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1602
   (root) at /Users/kshipley/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@split/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5
rake aborted!
```

Any ideas what the proper command is to re-enable the ObjectSpace when running rake? I have run commands like

```
bundle exec jruby -X+O test/functional/my_test.rb
bundle exec jruby -X+O -S irb
```

with no issues, so it seems somehow related to rake specifically.

Comment: What about `bundle exec jruby -X+O -S rake`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited concurrent to your comment -- that was the command I was actually running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your rake task spawn subprocesses? If so, JRuby might be reusing the current JVM process. Try exporting `JRUBY_OPTS='-X+O -J-Djruby.launch.inproc=false'`.

Comment: This does solve my problem, but my test execution time went from

real 0m14.867s
user 0m6.484s
sys 0m1.269s

under ree to

real 0m56.332s
user 1m11.491s
sys 0m5.107s

under jruby-1.6.2. Do you have any tuning suggestions, or should I consider isolating the one piece of code that needs to run jruby at the moment?